# Adding new line to text in Google spreadsheet cell via apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an apps script which takes email addresses from one spreadsheet from multiple cells and adds them them to another spreadsheet into 1 cell only.
Currently the email addresses are added to that cell and separated by a ", ".

I would like to add the email addresses into that same cell but add a new line after each address.

I know it is possible to have new lines in a cell when manually adding text, by typing CTRL-Enter.

How can this be achieved in apps script?

I have so far tried to append "\n" or "\r" or "\r\n" to the string, to no avail, so I have reverted my code back to adding ", " instead.

```
sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
sheet.clear();

sheet.appendRow(["Num Emails", "Emails"]);

var LMEmails = "";
var count  = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < reviewers.LMEmails.length; i++) {
  if (count) {
    LMEmails += ", " + reviewers.LMEmails[i];
  } else {
    LMEmails += reviewers.LMEmails[i];
  }
  count++;
}

data = [count, LMEmails];

sheet.appendRow(data);
```

If anyone could help, I would very much appreciate it

Regards
Crouz

Comment: Here `\n` is working just fine with `setValue()`. What does `LMEmails += "\n" + reviewers.LMEmails[i];` leads to?

Comment: It leads to xxxxx@xxx.comyyyyy@yyy.comzzzzz@zzz.com, but as you can see, I do not use setValue(). In reality, I have many more headers and columns to populate, the code you see there is truncated

Comment: Instead of appendRow use setValue. `ss.getRange( ss.getLastRow(), 0, 1, 2).setValue(data);`

Comment: I tried tat, but instead of updating the next empty row it updates the same row (top one), and strangely enough it updates all cells in the row with the same value, the first value in the data array.

Comment: Made a mistake in the getRange, correctly would be: `ss.getRange( ss.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, 2).setValue(data);`

Comment: Now all rows get added, but the value is still the first entry in the data array added to all cells, hmmmm, weird.

Comment: So it looks like this                                                                              
1 1 1 1 1                                                                           
2 2 2 2 2                                                                       
3 3 3 3 3
etc.

Comment: Data is a single Array, it need to be a double. Cahnge `data = [count, LMEmails];` to `data = [[count], [LMEmails]];`

Comment: Sorry, but that gives the same results as before. It's not a huge deal, I'll use the data the way it is, separated by commas. Thanks for the time and help @Kriggs.

Comment: I worked it out, it should be data = [[count, LMEmails]];

Answer (score 15):

After searching for the same question, this was my solution:

```
var stringToDisplay = 'FirstBit' + String.fromCharCode(10) + 'SecondBit';
```

then

```
workSheet.getRange(1,1).setValue(stringToDisplay);
```

output will be in a single cell, :
FirstBit
SecondBit

Answer (score 2):

Google Spreadsheets seems to ignore the new line if there are no characters *after* it.

Using "/n" works fine as long as you add at least one other character after it, this could be a space as shown below.

**For example:**

```
var myString = 'First Bit' + "\n " + "Second Bit";
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
data = [[count, LMEmails]];
```